# What is the relationship between values and meaning (in life)?

Tags: meaning-of-life, values, axiology

Please correct me if you think I am wrong, but it has become apparent to me that meaning - in the senses of significance of one's own life, purpose and sense-making - and values are inextricably linked, but what I am wondering is: what is this link?  Is it causal?  If so, in which direction?  Do they somehow mediate each other to some degree?

Any thoughts and/or references to learn more about this relationship would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Causality between values and meaning is as follows: The *instinct* of self-preservation manifests as the *intrinsic value* of self-preservation; when coupled with [knowledge of death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terror_management_theory), this value takes on the *instrumental aim* of abstract self-preservation, or meaning -- in the form of *legacy*, *symbolic immortality*, or *being a part of something greater*.

For an overview on the origin of values, see my answer [on the nature of personal values](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90639/what-are-personal-values-more-exactly/90652#90652).

Put simply, the will to live on, plus the thought of death, can resolve in meaning.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Could you point me in the direction of some papers, articles or books to learn more on the subject?