# What are the things that we "value" called?

Tags: ethics, terminology

So I have asked a few question about terminology, as I am here and there considering how to model various things. That brought me to [Morality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morality) because I was about to define a category of *things* called "values", like [this list here](https://jamesclear.com/core-values), which includes:

- authenticity
- achievement
- adventure
- authority
- autonomy
- balance
- beauty
- ...

But then I was thinking, really people could "value" anything. Some people could value "negative" things like pain and suffering as well, for whatever reason. So values could span the entire spectrum of possible things, good and bad.

That made me wonder, what are these listed "value" items actually though? Authenticity, a state of being maybe? Achievement, a result of positive action. Adventure, a quality of being. Autonomy, a feeling. I can't quite tell how to classify these things, these modern "values".

The problem is, in an ontology, saying that "these are values" is prescribing a certain morality, which some may agree with and others not. But what are these things then if considered outside of or more general than values? *Features* maybe?

Comment: It seems like you want something like: > [Value systems](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/value_system#English) based upon a quality such as:

Comment: Might these be termed *instruments,* similar to my usage [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90639/what-are-personal-values-more-exactly/90652#90652)? Consider also the other answers on that question. It seems pretty close to what you are asking here.