# What does something depend on to be morally valuable?

Tags: ethics, value-theory

First, what is the type of thing that can have value? (Actions, states of affairs, objects?) And then, what is it that makes something have value?

Comment: Do you mean, be a 'moral subject'? Or, defines the direction of 'moral progress'? Value is a really vague term, very subject to opinion, so not suitable for a question on this site, as is.

Comment: I mean what makes one thing better than another (in a moral sense).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps you could give context, how you came to this question, & what concrete issues you have in mind.

Comment: Presumably any mental object, or phenomenon, can be ascribed value. This value results from the interplay of instinct and experience. My answer [on the nature and origin of values](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90639/what-are-personal-values-more-exactly/90652#90652) provides more detail. For a sociological perspective, consider [Spiral Dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_Dynamics).