# Question for philosophers - How would you call the following view of the meaning of life?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, meaning-of-life

Question for philosophers - How would you call the following view of the meaning of life?: "There isn't much point in assessing the intrinsic or extrinsic value or meaning of life. Accept life as it is - even if it's futile or absurd - and simply focus on living."

Comment: Please clarify in what sense words intrinsic and extrinsic have been used and why you need them.

Comment: Some kind of Epicureanism, I guess.

Comment: It sounds like a crude version of [existentialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of "meaning of life" and why do people seek it?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/12672/9148)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good piece of advice only if you thought of humans only as  animals having some intelligence.

Not all human beings can focus on life alone (as you believe) because human beings have great intellectual capacity. This will motivate them to discover new areas of life. They will also try to maintain what they attained. Gradually they will try to find solutions about existence and about their own existence. If humans are the highest of all living things, it is an inevitable natural process for perfection.

So your philosophy will not work as one that applies to everyone.

If the great were born into this world, the following quote would not be in vain.

> Each soul is potentially divine. The goal is to manifest this divinity
> within by controlling nature, external and internal. Do this either by
> work, or worship, or psychic control, or philosophy – by one or more
> or all of these-and be free.
> -- Swami Vivekananda

https://www.swamivivekananda.guru/2017/04/26/each-soul-is-potentially-divine/