# Will we ever have an answer?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Why am I always asking myself questions that do not have answers? What is my purpose, why are we here? These questions cause me great anxiety.

I wish I could find a way to stop asking and just accept, but I cannot. How does one stop asking when one cannot find an answer? To me something is just not right about all of this. I find meaning for other things on the earth but I cannot find any true meaning for man. Air has a purpose. Plants have a purpose. Other animals have a purpose, etc. When it comes to humans, I go blank.

As you can tell by my writing, I am not your average high IQ individual but I am always looking for answers. This is one of the finest examples of how I think. Mr. Rust Cole explains us in this conversation from the 1st season of True Detective. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8x73UW8Hjk

I get chills when I listen to this. Why is it so hard for me to just let go? After all of these years of man being on this planet and we still do not have a reason as to why.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of "meaning of life" and why do people seek it?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/12666/what-is-the-meaning-of-meaning-of-life-and-why-do-people-seek-it)

Comment: We have [many questions about the meaning of life](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-of-life?tab=Votes) that may provide some insight into the answer. Many others have also discussed the topic elsewhere. The answer (finding your own meaning) may not be particularly satisfying, though, especially if you grew up believing there should be some greater transcendent meaning to life, or if you're struggling to find things that give you meaning. We do not prepare people well for finding meaning in life in adulthood.

Answer (score 0):

It may be some comfort to know that you are not alone. Many people feel much the same as you do.

The best answer I know of is not comfortable, but suggests a way of coping. Wittgenstein writes in *Philosophical Investigations* 133

> The real discovery is the one which enables me to stop doing philosophy when I want to. The one that gives philosophy peace, so that it is no longer tormented by questions which bring itself into question.

If you take this seriously, it turns out that the purpose of life is the search. It may or may not be endless, but it does at least have some prospect of peace at some point in the future.

It may help to mention the story (which I can't give you the source of) that he said, at the end of his life "Tell them I've had a wonderful life." So this may not be as bleak as it sounds.

I'm sorry I can't be more helpful than that.

I recommend, however, being as kind to people, including yourself, as you can.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know how or why the Universe is the way it is. If you accept mainstream science, then life on Earth seems to have evolved more or less by accident, with humans evolving from earlier animals. Given that, you should not expect to find definitive and specific answers to the types of questions that have been troubling you. The best advice I can give is that life is whatever you make of it. If you would like to be satisfied with your life, try thinking of people you admire and reflecting on why you admire them and how you can direct your energies in a similarly positive and constructive way. If you focus your thoughts, time and energy on the objective of having a positive impact on other people, you should find that a sufficiently rewarding purpose in itself.

Answer (score -1):

There is no set purpose, or reason why. These are things that you come up with by yourself. :)

Hope this helps: https://youtu.be/MBRqu0YOH14?si=MEN9b9JvfeuFvcxm

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).